# How to import static url using webpack

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, webpack

How can I import a static url using webpack:

`index.js`

`import 'http://google.com/myscript.js'`

Comment: Download it first. Webpack doesn't support downloading URLs during compile.

Answer (score 10):

It's really unclear what you're trying to do, but in general you have a few options.

1. **Pre-download the script or install it via NPM**. This probably is the preferred way to deal with external dependencies. Once it is local you can easily `import` or `require` it like any other module.
2. **If it absolutely must be loaded dynamically** you will need a 3rd party module such as https://www.npmjs.com/package/scriptjs which can easily download 3rd party modules at runtime and block the execution of the rest of the script until it has been parsed.
3. **Use a `<script>` tag and include it on your page**. This only works if it's a general dependency that can be loaded before everything else (maybe for a polyfill or a library you depend on everywhere like jquery.)

I hope that helps!

Comment: I used the third approach, my use case is for `signalr/hubs` url.

Answer (score 3):

[This webpack issue](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/8341#issuecomment-436550381) says you can use this comment to allow the import to just work.  Though this is only dynamic import not static.

```
import(/* webpackIgnore: true */ "https://example.com");
```

First seen here https://stackoverflow.com/a/69951351/4619267

Comment: This disables any webpack processing and just let the browser to handle `import` nativelly, as most browsers now can: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34607252/es6-import-module-from-url/70750023#70750023. This is the answer as of 2023. 

Comment: @AxeEffect. That may be true for JS files, but what about TypeScript?

Answer (score -3):

`import` is es6. With es5 and webpack, use `require`, or better wrap your JS files with AMD/UMD.