# Can I load a script and then make a variable pointing to that loaded script?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, scripting, webpack-2

Is there any way in javascript or react to load a script inside the index.html and then import that loaded script in another file?

```
index.html
  <body>
    <script
      type="text/javascript"
      src="http://localhost:3001/myService.js"
    ></script>
    <div id="root"></div>

  </body>


anyOtherComponent.js
import myService from "  ";
```

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ES6: import module from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34607252/es6-import-module-from-url)

Answer (score 1):

In short, not really. Your best bet is to download the file in question.

Please refer to this answer as well:

[ES6: import module from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34607252/es6-import-module-from-url)