# Assign namespaces to src library files

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, namespaces, type-declaration

I have a website made in ReactJS. The website calls functions of a library `analyzejs` generated by another programming language. I can only call functions of this library; I cannot modify much the content of this library.

So far, I have been using the first version of the library: `analyzejs-v1.js`. To achieve this, in `frontend/public/index.html` of the website, I have

```
<head>
  <script src="/lib/analyzejs-v1.js"></script>
  <!-- <script src="/lib/analyzejs-v2.js"></script> -->
</head>
<body>
  <div id="root"></div>
</body>
```

I also have a type declaration file `frontend/src/defines/analyzejs-v1.d.ts` as follows:

```
declare function f1(): string;
declare function f2(): string;
...
```

As a result, in the code of the website, I could call directly `f1()` to use `analyzejs-v1.js`.

Now, I would like to add another version of the library `analyzejs-v2.js`. In some part of the website, I want to call `f1()` of `analyzejs-v1.js`; in some part of the website, I want to call `f1()` of `analyzejs-v2.js`. So I guess I need to add namespaces such as `v1` and `v2` to these different versions to avoid conflict. Then, I will be able to call `v1.f1()` and `v2.f2()`.

I tried to modify `frontend/src/defines/analyzejs-v1.d.ts` as follows:

```
declare namespace v1 {
    function f1(): string;
    function f2(): string;
    ...
}
```

And in the code of the website, I tried to use `v1.f1()`.

The compilation did not raise any error. However, running the website and using features calling `v1.f1()` returned me an error on `v1.f1()`: `Unhandled Rejection (ReferenceError): v1 is not defined`.

Does anyone know how to add a namespace to such a library?

Answer (score 0):

If you [import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) these files in your code like so:

```
import analyzejs-v1 from '/lib/analyzejs-v1.js'
import analyzejs-v2 from '/lib/analyzejs-v2.js'
```

in your code you can call them under different objects:

```
analyzejs-v1.f();
analyzejs-v2.f();
```

Comment: I could not change much about `analyzejs-v1.js` and `analyzejs-v2.js`. In ReactJS, is it possible to put them under objects?

Comment: @SoftTimur updated answer, do you have to import these as script tag?

Comment: I just tried import, the compilation raised an error `FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory`, probably because my `/lib/analyzejs-v1.js` is too big (6Mo).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34607252/es6-import-module-from-url

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to group the functions inside your javascript files into classes or objects

```js
// test.js
const testNamespace = {
    print = () => console.log('print was called from test.js')
}
```

```js
// test1.js
const anotherNamespace = {
    print = () => console.log('print was called from test1.js')
}
```

now you can call these functions using

```js
anotherNamespace.print();
testNamespace.print();
```

Comment: I could not change much about `analyzejs-v1.js` and `analyzejs-v2.js`; I need to modify on the side of ReactJS.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem** - you are only using typescript type declarations, which are deleted on compilation, completely not doing anything at runtime. JavaScript actually doesn't support namespaces, only global scope, function scope and block scope.

**Solution #1** - using es6 import syntax, which creates a function scope around the imported script (referred to as a module). And even better, React supports dynamic imports, which gives you both a module "namespace", and automatic code splitting, which could help with your heap memory issues:

```
// Page1.tsx
import("/lib/analyzejs-v1.js").then(module => {
  module.f1();
  module.f2();
});
// Page2.tsx
import("/lib/analyzejs-v2.js").then(module => {
  module.f1();
  module.f2();
});
```

The dynamic import splits the JS bundle so that the dynamically required JS parts are in separated files, and run only when import() is called. This could  help with really large files and memory issues.
import() returns a promise, which gets the module as an argument when resolved.

**Solution #2** - use the import syntax `import * as moduleName from "module/url"`. This import method contains the functions in the module to an object with the name of your choosing, but everything will be in the main bundle as apposed to dynamic imports:

```
import * as moduleV1 from "/lib/analyzejs-v1.js";
import * as moduleV2 from "/lib/analyzejs-v2.js";
      
moduleV1.f1();
moduleV1.f2();

moduleV2.f1();
moduleV2.f2();
```

Comment: Thank you. All my functions that call `f1()` and `f2()` are non-asynchronous. If I want to use `import` as you suggested, does it mean that I need to change all these functions to asynchronous?

Comment: @SoftTimur In this case, I'm using `.then` on the dynamic import promise, so no need to change the function to async. But of course, it really depends on want you want to do.

Comment: You are already using `.then` in `import("/lib/analyzejs-v1.js").then(module => { ... })`, no? I don't see how to write it in other ways.

Comment: Additionally, `import` gives me a warning `File '....../frontend/public/lib/analyzejs-v1.js' is not a module.`

Comment: @SoftTimur so perhaps your package does not support the syntax. Could you try just using: 
`const moduleV1 = require("/lib/analyzejs-v1.js");`
`const moduleV2 = require("/lib/analyzejs-v2.js");`
then use moduleV1  and moduleV2 as your namespaces.

Comment: `const moduleV1 = require("/lib/analyzejs-v1.js");` or `import * as moduleV2 from "/lib/analyzejs-v2.js";` return `FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory`. https://pastebin.com/raw/5GLX5k2v

Comment: @SoftTimur OK, another complementary approach would be to use import/require, but in a worker thread, in an attempt to save some memory: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers

Answer (score 0):

So you want to wrap different versions of a vanilla javascript library into a bundled script library and selectively call either in a browser?

This solution uses npm, browserify, `require` and `module.exports`.

The strategy is to add a module.exports to the vanilla libraries and then bundle them together as globals `v1` and `v2`.

So setup a folder for building the bundled libraries.

```bash
$ mkdir bundle-analyzers
$ cd bundle-analyzers
$ npm init

package name: (bundle-analyzers)
version: (1.0.0)
description: bundle versions of analyzejs with browserify
entry point: (index.js)
test command:
git repository:
keywords:
author:
license: (ISC)
```

Create a `lib` folder and copy the analyzejs files into it

```
+--bundle-analyzer
|   +-- lib
|   |   analyzejs-v1.js
|   |   analyzejs-v2.js
*
```

For simplicity, let's assume both analyzejs versions have a common method named `version()`.  Let's expose both
by adding the following to the end of each analyzejs-v*.js file:

```js
module.exports = { 
  version
}
```

Create a file `analyzejs-bundler.js` which will expose both library's exports globally:

```js
var v1 = require("./lib/analyzejs-v1.js");
var v2 = require("./lib/analyzejs-v2.js"); 
window["v1"] = v1;
window["v2"] = v2;
```

Install browserify in the root folder

```bash
$ npm i browserify
```

Add an `index.html` to the project folder which will demo the bundle:

```html
<html>
<head>
  <script src="./bundle/analyzejs-bundle.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <pre id="versions"></pre>
  <script>
    window.addEventListener('load', () => {
      document.getElementById('versions').innerText = [v1.version(), v2.version()].join('\n');
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Now add a script to package.json to create the bundle:

```json
"scripts": {
  "bundler": "browserify ./analyzejs-bundler.js -o ./bundle/analyzejs-bundle.js"
}
```

Create the bundle

```bash
$ npm run bundle
```

OK so the folder structure should be

```
+--bundle-analyzer
|   +-- bundle
|   |   analyzejs-bundle.js
|   +-- lib
|   |   analyzejs-v1.js
|   |   analyzejs-v2.js
|   +-- node_modules
|   |   { node stuff }
|   analyzejs-bundler.js
|   index.html
|   package-lock.json
|   package.json
*
```

Open up index.html from the file system and verify.

Of course if there a zillion exports from the analyzejs library something more sophisticated will be required.

Note it is also possible to create a monolith for versions of analyzejs which may be more suitable:

```js
var v1 = require("./lib/analyzejs-v1.js");
var v2 = require("./lib/analyzejs-v2.js"); 
window["analyzejs"] = { v1, v2 }
```

YMMV.  The ambient definitions for Typescript depend on the global variables defined and are simply a tedious sideshow to the solution IMO.

Comment: Thank you for this long answer, I will try and let you know.

Comment: Let  me know how it turns out. NPM tooling is getting unruly IMO.