# Using Webpack, how to dynamically load an external module built with another Webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, micro-frontend, es6-modules

Let's say I manage 2 JavaScript projects both built with Webpack:

- A Website called **User-Website**
- A JavaScript module called **External-Module**

Note that I'm using 2 separate projets for the same reasons described by the [Micro Front end](https://martinfowler.com/articles/micro-frontends.html) architecture.

I want my **User-Website** to be able to dynamically load **External-Module** on demand (using any JavaScript module technology). My **User-Website** knows at build-time the URL where to reach **External-Module**.

I can chose whatever technology is needed on both *User-Website* and **External-Module**.

I'm looking for a solution:

- That is easy to implement (maybe JSONP that Webpack already handles to dynamically load chunks?)
- That doesn't add to much overhead on both **User-Website** and **External-Module** (For example [JavaScript modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules) looks good but requires a lot of polyfilling)

My question is related to https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/7526

---

I tried to use JSONP library output on my **External-Module** but I don't know how to load it in **User-Website**.

I'm also thinking about using the [SystemJS](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs) in **User-Website** to dynamically load **External-Module**:

- I could also replace internal JSONP mechanism with SystemJS within Webpack (to save having JSONP mechanism in m bundles).
- [SystemJS](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs) looks better and more modern than [RequireJS](https://requirejs.org/)
- This will require to add [SystemJS](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs) (`s.js` only) overhead.. I'm trying to use less dependencies as possible.

Comment: Quite related to https://stackoverflow.com/q/50097327/1480391

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry if I did not get the question but I've recently made a project based on the article from the link You've provided. 
Can't You just host both of the applications and load the part of `chunk.js` on the runtime ? It's how this particular article's example works. There is an example provided in the article. Some restaurant app with different microfrontends loaded dynamically on the runtime. Isn't it exactly what You need ?

Below code is the 'heart' of this particular example. Take a look.

```js
componentDidMount() {
    const { name, host } = this.props;
    const scriptId = `micro-frontend-script-${name}`;

    if (document.getElementById(scriptId)) {
      this.renderMicroFrontend();
      return;
    }

    fetch(`${host}/asset-manifest.json`)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(manifest => {
        const script = document.createElement('script');
        script.id = scriptId;
        script.src = `${host}${manifest['main.js']}`;
        script.onload = this.renderMicroFrontend;
        document.head.appendChild(script);
      });
  }
```