# how to access component from different port

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Just for example If I have URL www.testonly.com with 3 different ports 3000, 3001, 3002

Then I have app running on port 3000 and 3001
Now I want to access any component from the app running on port :3001 in the app running on :3000

Is it possible to do so, will cross-origin policy has something to do with it, 
how I will be able to achieve this kind of functionality

Also I don't want to use `<iframe />` html tag for this, as any changes in the origin component will affect every component where I am using `<iframe />`

I want to achieve something like below

```
      <Router>       
         <Route path="/test" render={(props) => <ComponentFromOtherPort {...state} {...props} />} />         
      </Router>
```

1. Here `<ComponentForOtherPort />` is the component whose code is running on 
   port :3001
2. React routers are present on the app running on port :3000

Every time, I want to send different values with `<ComponentForOtherPort />` and on that component I want that props to be used something like below.

```
//code on :3001
class ComponentForOtherPort extends React.Component{    
componentDidMount(){    
 //props 
 console.log(this.props);
 }
}
```

Comment: That's a strange use-case, but I think what you need here is a dynamic import from a URL which ES modules don't support, so you'll have to look for a different solution - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50097327/using-a-full-url-in-a-dynamic-import. I am still unclear what you want to do exactly, but using what I just mentioned wouldn't affect components running on `3001` if you use them on `3000`. You won't have the ability to share `state` between `3000` and `3001`, for example, if that's what you're aiming at - **this is not possible** by using just `React` and dynamic imports.

Comment: Hello @goto1, thanks for the suggestion, I'll try to implement it with the help of dynamic import as suggested by you, maybe that can work :)