# CORS error when using await import() with Google API

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, import, async-await

Why I get a CORS error:

```
Access to script at 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

When I try to import dynamically Google Maps API in my **JavaScript**:

```js
  await import('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js')
```

But not when I do it in my **HTML**:

```html
  <script defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
```

Any idea would be really appreciate it.

**Note**: if I import other URL libraries I don't have problems, ex: hammer.js cdn

```js
async function init_map() {
  await import('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js')
}

init_map()
```

Comment: What does the error you get say?  Perhaps google doesn't set the CORS permissions to allow it, while the other ones do

Comment: Thank you so much @geocodezip for your answer : ), I have updated the post with the CORS error: has been blocked by CORS policy...

Comment: but if google doesn't allow it why I'm able to do it in the HTML?

Comment: This is basically what I explained to you yesterday. Some endpoints allow cross-origin requests, some don't. Google doesn't, at least for the Maps API. Here is some more info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50097327/using-a-full-url-in-a-dynamic-import

Comment: @MrUpsidown you are back, thanks! it says "web browsers do implement dynamic loading over HTTP" So, Google allows me to use Google Maps API if I import it in HTML tag but not in JavaScript. What's the different how they know it?

Comment: Browsers don't check the CORS policy for loading with script tags, they do for dynamic loading.

Comment: Now everything is totally clear @geocodezip that was the thing I was missing! Thanks a lot, I'm a newbie

Answer (score 0):

I found asolution. But I am not sure if this is working everywhere.

At least it is working on current Chrome, Firefox and Edge Browser.

```
var url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true&libraries=places&key=" + gkey;
$(document.head).append($('<script>', { src: url }));
```

Comment: Thank you so much Philipp for your solution but I would like to use dynamically imports as I do with other endpoints : )

Comment: You can define the url dynamically that way. And that way you don't need to worry about CORS permissions.