# The target environment doesn't support dynamic import() syntax so it's not possible to use external type 'module' within a script

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, import, dynamic-import

I Just created a react app. The `npm start` seems to work fine but `npm run build` is constantly failing. I need to run `npm run build` to deploy it on some website.

Already gone through all posts related to this on `stackoverflow.com`. But didn't found any working solution.

```js
import './App.css';
import 'https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js'

import Navbar from './components/navbar';
import Homepage from './components/homepage';
import Skills from './components/Skills';
import Project from './components/project';
import Contact from './components/contact';
```

**Error Message**

```
Failed to compile.

The target environment doesn't support dynamic import() syntax so it's not possible to use external type 'module' within a script
```

Comment: How did you create the project?

Comment: I used `npx create-react-app <project-name>`

Comment: I guess that's because of this line `import 'https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js'`. Why don't you use `font-awesome` from npm?

Comment: I did remove that line. But unfortunately nothing changed!! Is there anything else i can do... its been very long and its not resolving..

Comment: Do you have more imports like this?

Comment: will that be a problem too? `@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins&display=swap");`

Comment: I don't think so

Comment: finally the process is done!! the command worked... There was one more import font statement just as the same above one. and after removing that build command run successfully... Thank you very much..!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here was the import statement of an external js file.

```
import 'https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js';
```

You can add the file in index.html & run build.

```
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js"></script>
```

And yes there's no problem with import statement in css.

```
@import url("https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/remixicon@2.5.0/fonts/remixicon.css");
```

Comment: Does this work with TypeScript?

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it was failing because using external styles

```
import "https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.css";
```

Fixed with using via npm:
`npm i leaflet`

```
import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css';
```

Official [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/built-in-css-support#import-styles-from-node_modules)

Answer (score 0):

To dynamically import ES modules you'll need to [change webpack's output type to ESM](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputmodule).

Alternatively you could try [ignoring the external import with `webpackIgnore`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69951351/1763012).