# yarn build not creating build folder

Tags: reactjs, react-native, yarnpkg

I am trying to run `yarn build` but the command fails. Can anyone help me to solve this issue? The Node version using is v14.1.0 and Yarn version is 1.22.19. The `yarn start` command works but not the `build` command.

[image: Screenshot of the issue]

package.json file

```
{
  "name": "queenofraw",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "homepage": "https://ja.materiamx.com",
  "main": "",
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.18.6",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.10.4",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.4",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.4",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^5.3.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.3.1",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.3",
    "@material-ui/core": "^3.0.1",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^3.0.1",
    "@mdi/svg": "^3.0.39",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.10.3",
    "@mui/material": "^5.10.3",
    "@react-jvectormap/core": "^1.0.3",
    "@rematch/core": "^0.6.0",
    "@stripe/stripe-js": "^1.8.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^14.4.3",
    "antd": "^3.10.4",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.3",
    "chart.js": "^4.1.1",
    "classnames": "^2.2.6",
    "country-list": "^2.1.0",
    "echarts": "^4.2.0-rc.2",
    "echarts-for-react": "^2.0.15-beta.0",
    "err": "^2.1.12",
    "events": "^2.0.0",
    "formsy-react": "^1.1.4",
    "image-to-base64": "^2.0.1",
    "jquery": "^3.6.1",
    "js-cookie": "^2.2.0",
    "loadash": "^1.0.0",
    "material-ui-table-edit": "^3.0.3",
    "moment": "^2.22.0",
    "namor": "^1.1.1",
    "qs": "^6.9.4",
    "query-parse": "^2.0.0",
    "rc-queue-anim": "^1.6.7",
    "react": "^16.4.2",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.7.0",
    "react-chartjs-2": "^5.1.0",
    "react-confirm": "^0.1.17",
    "react-cookie": "^3.0.4",
    "react-country-flag": "^1.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.2",
    "react-dropzone": "^7.0.1",
    "react-fontawesome": "^1.6.1",
    "react-google-recaptcha": "^2.1.0",
    "react-icons": "^3.2.2",
    "react-images-upload": "^1.2.3",
    "react-inline-editing": "^1.0.10",
    "react-jvectormap": "0.0.4",
    "react-moment": "^0.8.3",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "react-router-redux": "^4.0.8",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "react-scroll": "^1.7.11",
    "react-table": "^6.8.6",
    "recharts": "^1.2.0",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1",
    "socket.io-client": "1.7.0",
    "superagent": "^4.0.0-beta.5",
    "web-vitals": "^3.0.1",
    "yarn": "1.22.19"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "cross-env REACT_APP_SERVER=https://api-dev.materiamx.com react-scripts start",
    "starts": "PORT=6500 REACT_APP_SERVER=http://localhost:5080  react-scripts start",
    "sass:watch": "node-sass -w src/assets/scss/style.scss -o src/assets/css",
    "sass:build": "node-sass src/assets/scss/style.scss -o src/assets/css --source-map true",
    "dev": "npm-run-all --parallel start sass:watch",
    "start:stag": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "cross-env REACT_APP_SERVER=http://192.168.2.18:5080 react-scripts build",
    "deploy": "aws s3 sync build/ s3://qor-mmx-static --acl public-read",
    "stag:build": "REACT_APP_SERVER=https://api-dev.materiamx.com react-scripts build",
    "prod:build": "REACT_APP_SERVER=https://api-dev.materiamx.com/ react-scripts build",
    "stag": "yarn run stag:build && sls client deploy --stage staging --aws-profile qor --region us-east-1",
    "prod": "yarn run prod:build && sls client deploy --stage production --aws-profile qor --region us-east-1",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx-source": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "flow-bin": "^0.68.0",
    "node-sass": "^8.0.0",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
    "react-edit-inline": "^1.0.8",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.2.0",
    "serverless-finch": "^2.2.0",
    "serverless-single-page-app-plugin": "^1.0.2"
  },
  "jest": {},
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The target environment doesn't support dynamic import() syntax so it's not possible to use external type 'module' within a script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74143299/the-target-environment-doesnt-support-dynamic-import-syntax-so-its-not-possi)

Comment: Thanks for the help i already reviewed but not have any points to sort my issue

Answer (score 0):

when i tried `npx serve -s build` command it worked . May someone find this as a help in the future

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Can you please try `npm run build`.

Regards

Comment: Thanks for the help..but still not working